# Analysis using ANOVA

Tags: r, anova, categorical-data, experiment-design

I want to compare 6 designs of spoons (D1,D2,D3,D4,D5,D6) in 20 children (blocks).I also want to see whether holding the spoon in right or left hand affects food-pinching response(number of M&M's picked and placed in cup). 
I have dataset with response % noted for each design type on all of the 20 children, and the information about which hand is used is represented as zero or one.

I am using Randomized Complete Block Design (with children as blocks) to perform the test.
I can use ANOVA in R to check the effect:

```
summary(aov(response~blocks+designs))
```

Should children and  hand data be included in the model. Would the information about hand impact the outcome.

**EDIT**:
I am confused about how to compare whether holding spoon in right or left hand affects the number of M&M's picked. Should this information change the above mentioned ANOVA analysis.

Below is the sample of data set which includes data for only 10 children for two design types.

```
Response  Design Children Hand
20.11   D1  1   0
30.26   D1  2   1
28.56   D1  3   1
23.19   D1  4   1
23.29   D1  5   0
27.62   D1  6   0
29.0    D1  7   1
30.5    D1  8   1
28.23   D1  9   0
29.98   D1  10  1
25.7    D2  1   0
26.2    D2  2   1
19.2    D2  3   1
24.32   D2  4   1
25.3    D2  5   0
30.45   D2  6   0
28.98   D2  7   1
18.85   D2  8   1
32.7    D2  9   0
29.8    D2  10  1
```

Any pointers will be helpful.

Comment: Number of M&M's is a ratio scale, so ANOVA is tenable as to scale.  Are you asking if you can add handedness as a factor to the ANOVA?  If so, I think it might not be tenable with N of 20.  If you are assuming all kids are right handed and you want to see how much difference it makes if the left hand is used, you might have difficulty as the number of cases in each cell will be up to the choices made by the kids, so you will have different N's in the cells and perhaps some empty cells.  If you have not collected the data yet, perhaps you can give the kids the spoon in their right or left hand.

Comment: So, this would simple be one way ANOVA problem. I have the data set which has 0 or 1 based on which hand is used.

Comment: Please explain exactly what the response variable represents.

Comment: Response is food-pinching efficiency i.e.(number of M&M's picked and placed in cup)

Comment: @user30438 This *is not* a simple one-way ANOVA problem because you have a *repeated measures* design (i.e. the same 10 children using the six different spoon designs). It is also not a one-way design because you have two factors (spoon and hand).

Answer (score 1):

This is a repeated-measure experiment. Use the following code in R:

```
fit<-aov(response~ factor(design)*factor(hand) + Error(factor(children)), data=data)
summary(fit)
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly if you  are measuring your data in percentages  your outcome variable must be measured in 0s and 1s. (perhaps did pick up an M&M vs didn't???) In this case your data is binary and based on the binomial distribution.  Strictly speaking should be using logistic regression, or a chi squared test not ANOVA.   there maybe cases where using ANOVA is permissible with binary data (e.g where N is high enough) but this is a separate question....  My advice is to consider logistic regression analysis instead or chi squared test.  You can measure the same things as ANOVA using these tests - but they are specifically designed to deal with data measured in 0s and 1s,  rather than data collected with  continous measures.  if you need further help with these tests then you can post questions on this site.

Comment: Why do you say that number of M&Ms is a 0-1 scale?

Comment: Outcome variable is not 0 or 1, but it is efficiency %. I am not interested in testing whether they picked the M&M or not, but in efficiency of picking M&M's based on spoon design. And does left or right hand plays any role there.

Comment: What did the first person do to get a score of 20.11? I do not understand the data. Did the person pick up 20.11% of M&M's in a large bowl of M&M's, or of M&M's attempted, or something else?